# MGET tools in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: web, arcgis

(I tried to research this question but I didn't find anything pertinent)

Is it possible to add MGET tool (Marine Geospatial Ecology Tools) for a map in ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the developer of MGET. As far as I know, the answer is no, this cannot be done at this time. There are two problems.

First, MGET itself would have to be capable of being hosted as a geoprocessing service. While I do not know of anything specific that would prevent this, MGET is a fairly complicated Python package. Depending on what tool you are running, MGET will dynamically load other software libraries (e.g. R) into the process that MGET is running in, or create child Python processes to run code that requires something that cannot be safely loaded into an ArcGIS process (e.g. the MATLAB Component Runtime that MGET uses cannot be loaded into an ArcGIS process due to a "DLL Hell" problem concerning the xerces-c library that both ArcGIS and MATLAB use). While I have tested these various scenarios from the interactive ArcGIS Desktop applications, I am unsure they would work in the highly secure web-server scenario (e.g. from an IIS worker process).

Second, once the problems above were resolved, someone (e.g. us) would have to host an Internet-facing ArcGIS Server that offered the MGET tools for use by anyone on the Internet. Although this would be very cool, it has a cost and complexity to it that we are not presently able to afford. We are an academic laboratory, and while we do maintain various other Internet-facing services relating to our other research projects, we do not currently have funding to support this for MGET geoprocessing.

Sorry for the technical nature of this post, and that the answer is basically no at this time. I hope this helps.

Comment: can MGET tools be downloaded onto QGIS to do analysis?

Comment: Sorry, not at this time. We have done some preparatory work to build an MGET QGIS plugin but have not found funding to complete the development.